# tsql proc logic help

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am weak in SQL  and need some help working through some logic with my proc.

Three pieces: store procedure, table1, table2

Table 1 stores most recent data for specific IDs

```
Customer_id status_dte  status_cde    app_dte
001         2010-04-19  Y             2010-04-19
```

Table 2 stores history of data for specific customer IDs:
For example:

```
Log_id  customer_Id status_dte  status_cde
01     001         2010-04-20   N
02      001         2010-04-19   Y      
03      001         2010-04-19   N
04      001         2010-04-19   Y
```

The stored proecure currently throws an error if the status date from
table1 is < than app_date in table1.

```
If @status_dte < app_date
    Error
```

Note: @status_dte is a variable stored as the status_dte from table1

However, I want it to throw an error when the EARLIEST status_dte from
table 2 with a status_cde of 'Y' is less than the app_dte column in
table 1.

Keep in mind that this earliest date is not stored anywhere, the history
of data changes per customer. Another customer might have the following
history.

```
Log_id  customer_Id status_dte  status_cde
01     002         2010-04-20  N
02      002         2010-04-18  N       
03      002         2010-04-19  Y
04      002         2010-04-19  Y
```

Any ideas on how I can approach this?

Comment: Is one of the parameters of the sp @CustomerId or should this evaluate all rows in Table2?

Comment: What version of SQL Server/Sybase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test in one go per customer to find where the earliest date is less than the appdate using this construct

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT *
    FROM
      mytable M
      JOIN
      HistoryTable H ON M.customer_Id = H.customer_Id
    WHERE
      H.status_cde = 'Y'
    GROUP BY
      H.customer_Id, M.app_dte
    HAVING
     MIN(H.status_dte) < M.app_dte)
  ...error...
```

Answer (score 0):

If instead of a single customer, you wanted a list of customers with their earliest status date prior to the app_date, you could do something like:

```
;With 
    CustomerStatusDates As
    (
        Select T2.customer_id, Min(T2.status_dte) As MinDate
        From Table2 As T2
        Where status_cte = 'Y'
        Group By T2.customer_id
    )
Select ....
From Table1 As T1
    Join CustomerStatusDates As T2
        On T2.Customer_Id = T1.Customer_Id
Where T2.MinDate < T1.app_dte
```